# Javascript callback function as a optional parameter for a function

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which takes two arguments. First one is necessary and the second one is optional. The second argument is a callback function. How do I provide callback function as a default argument. The code that I wrote had errors.
The code that I tried:

```
function doSomething(count,() => {}) {
//code
}
```

Comment: That is an okay default function, what is the error you are getting? Tracebacks or exceptions should give a clue as to why it is not working.

Comment: @Nishant It says that the parameter declaration is expected

Comment: Oh wait, you are declaring it , sorry I was thinking this is a calling code. Yes, in that case just check for `undefined`. like mentioned below.

Comment: @Nishant so can I call the same function only one parameter in another place

Comment: Yeah. In JS, if you don't supply an argument, it will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default value for function parameter like below way.

```
function doSomething(count, fn = (() => {})) {
  //code
  //here fn is reference to the second parameter
}
```

Below is an example.

```js
function doSomething(count,fn = (() => {})) {
    console.log(fn())
}


doSomething(1, () => {return 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use call methods for this scenario

```js
function doSomeThing(param1, fn) {

// you should callback function
(fn ? fn : yourCustomeFunction).call(this)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any argument not passed in to a function has the value of `undefined`. Just check to see if the callback is defined:

```
function doSomething(count,callback) {
    // code
    if (callback !== undefined) {
        callback()
    }
}
```

To be safer, you can also check if callback is a function:

```
function doSomething(count,callback) {
    // code
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(count,callback) {
    // code
    if (!!callback) {
        callback()
    }
}
```

Check whether the second argument is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

To provide callback as default argument, you can try :

```
const doSomeAction = (callback = Function()) => {
  // write code here
  callback();
}

doSomeAction();
```

However, there are lot of other ways of doing , I prefer this approach as it's cleaner.